# TFTP over the WAN - would this matter?

Tags: switch, wan, tftp

I'm trying to figure out if there's a likely scenario where users connected to a virtual switch would have an occasion to need TFTP services to be forwarded over the WAN connection.  Wouldn't it be more likely they would use FTP instead?

In my situation, I have some additional information:
My user-base would consist of hotel guests that would probably only be using web access, but I ask because I'm not sure how common tftp use is over the internet. I didn't want to go blocking things if someome could plausibly need it, but if the usage scenario for tftp is loading firmware, it's well outside of my realm of concern.

Comment: Depends on what they're doing. I personally avoid TFTP over WANs because of the nature of the protocol (udp, per-packet ack), but sometimes it's the only way to load firmware/config/license/etc. Not to go all 6-sigma, but you need to talk to your users (customers?) to know what they need.

Comment: I guess I should rephrase the question to: in a normal usage scenario, would users of any network really have a general need for tftp.  For instance, do any major desktop applications rely on it or (firmware loading aside) would it be a major problem to not have TFTP access?

Comment: How else can we say "*I don't know what your users need*"?

Comment: What type of normal usage scenario? Are you an ISP? Running an EDU network? Research or purely academic? Corporate? Tech, software, manufacturing, or what? Something else entirely? What devices, services, and applications are in use on the network? Or let me ask this a different way, is there a specific reason you are looking to block TFTP?

Comment: My user-base would consist of hotel guests that would probably only be using web access, but I ask because I'm not sure how common tftp use is over the internet.  I didn't want to go blocking things if someome could plausibly need it, but if the usage scenario for tftp is loading firmware, it's well outside of my realm of concern.

Comment: @Volumetricsteve, go ahead and edit your questions to include the information you have provided in comments.  This will improve the question and automatically start a re-open vote process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's *probably* safe to block on the WAN. I wouldn't be surprise to find an application is using TFTP over the internet, but it would be *rare*.[*]

The real question is *do you know what your users need*? Will those users understand why Application Foo is broken because TFTP is blocked? (do they know what TFTP *is*?)

[*] Netopia used to "support" this. I always thought it was stupid, and rarely worked, but you *could* tell your netopia device to fetch images directly from netopia.